# Unable to connect GRPC microservice with client - Nest JS Node on k8s

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, grpc, grpc-node, linkerd

I'm currently stuck with connecting clusterIp  services in kubernetes. The main goal is to connect one pod (microservice) using grpc  and other pod (client) using node .
I'm using the service name to expose and connect to the microservice products-microservice  but I'm getting this error when try to call the microservice on the client.

```
"Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses",
            "    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)",
            "    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1209:28)",
            "    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)",
            "    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)",
            "    at callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:847:24)"
```

I review the docker image that I created and it's pointing to this address url: `'0.0.0.0:50051'`  but not working as this article recommends https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/11/07/grpc-load-balancing-on-kubernetes-without-tears/
Until now I have just one microservice for products that contains the logic to manage products  and was developed with node-js and grpc (locally works perfect). I named `xxx-microservice-products-deployment`  and contains their definition in k8s looks like:

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pinebox-microservice-products-deployment
  labels:
    app: pinebox
    type: microservice
    domain: products
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: pinebox-microservice-products-pod
      labels:
        app: pinebox
        type: microservice
        domain: products
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: pg-container
          image: postgres
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: testuser
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: testpass
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: db_development
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
        - name: microservice-container
          image: registry.digitalocean.com/pinebox/pinebox-microservices-products:latest
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pinebox
      type: microservice
      domain: products
```

Then in order to connect to them, we create a service with a `clusterIp`  that exposes the `50051` , and their definition in k8s looks like:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pinebox-products-microservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: pinebox
    type: microservice
    domain: products
  ports:
    - targetPort: 50051
      port: 50051
```

Now, we create a client in node too, that contains the api  `(get,post)`  methods that under the hood make the connection with the microservice. I named the client `xxx-api-main-app-deployment` and their definition in k8s looks like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pinebox-api-main-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: pinebox
    type: api
    domain: main-app
    role: users-service
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: pinebox-api-main-app-pod
      labels:
        app: pinebox
        type: api
        domain: main-app
        role: products-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: pinebox-api-main-app-container
          image: registry.digitalocean.com/pinebox/pinebox-main-app:latest
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pinebox
      type: api
      domain: main-app
      role: products-service
```

Also, I create a service to export the api and their k8s definition looks like:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pinebox-api-main-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: pinebox
    type: api
    domain: main-app
    role: products-service
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: name-of-the-port
      port: 3333
      targetPort: 3333
      nodePort: 30003
```

Until here, all looks good. So I tried to make the connection with the service but I got this error

```
"Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses",
            "    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)",
            "    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1209:28)",
            "    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)",
            "    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)",
            "    at callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:847:24)"
```

I didn't find anything useful to make it work. Anyone has any clues ?

So, after digging into a solution for the issue, I found that the kubernetes team recommend to use `linkerd` to literally convert the connection to http  due to the k8s doesn't work in this case. So I followed this post https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/11/07/grpc-load-balancing-on-kubernetes-without-tears/, then I go to the `linkerd` guide and follow the installation steps.
Now I was able to see the `linkeird` dashboard, but not able to communicate the microservice with the client.  So I tried to check if the port was exposed in the client pod so, I validate using this command:

```sh
$ kubectl exec -i -t pod/pinebox-api-main-app-deployment-5fb5d4bf9f-ttwn5 --container pinebox-api-
main-app-container -- /bin/bash
$ pritnenv
```

and this was the output:

```
PINEBOX_PRODUCTS_MICROSERVICE_PORT_50051_TCP_PORT=50051
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
PINEBOX_PRODUCTS_MICROSERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=50051
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
PINEBOX_API_MAIN_APP_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT_NAME_OF_THE_PORT=3333
PORT=3000
NODE_VERSION=12.18.2
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
PINEBOX_API_MAIN_APP_SERVICE_PORT_3333_TCP_PORT=3333
PINEBOX_PRODUCTS_MICROSERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=10.105.230.111
TERM=xterm
PINEBOX_API_MAIN_APP_SERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.106.81.212:3333
SHLVL=1
PINEBOX_PRODUCTS_MICROSERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.105.230.111:50051
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
PINEBOX_PRODUCTS_MICROSERVICE_PORT_50051_TCP=tcp://10.105.230.111:50051
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PINEBOX_API_MAIN_APP_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=3333
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1
_=/usr/bin/printenv
root@pinebox-api-main-app-deployment-5fb5d4bf9f-ttwn5:/usr/src/app#
```

So as you can see there is and env variable that contains the port for the service, for this is working. I'm not using the IP direclty, because it won't work when I scale the deployment to have more resources.
Then, I validate that my microservice was running using :

```
kubectl logs pod/xxx-microservice-products-deployment-78df57c96d-tlvvj -c microservice-container
```

and this was the output:

```
[Nest] 1   - 07/25/2020, 4:23:22 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 1   - 07/25/2020, 4:23:22 PM   [InstanceLoader] PineboxMicroservicesProductsDataAccessModule dependencies initialized +12ms
[Nest] 1   - 07/25/2020, 4:23:22 PM   [InstanceLoader] PineboxMicroservicesProductsFeatureShellModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 1   - 07/25/2020, 4:23:22 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +0ms       
[Nest] 1   - 07/25/2020, 4:23:22 PM   [NestMicroservice] Nest microservice successfully started +22ms[Nest] 1   - 07/25/2020, 4:23:22 PM   Microservice Products is listening +15ms
```

All looks good. So then I re-validate which port I'm using on the code:

- Microservice

```
const microservicesOptions = {
 transport: Transport.GRPC,
 options: {
   url: '0.0.0.0:50051',
   credentials: ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),
   package: 'grpc.health.v1',
   protoPath: join(__dirname, 'assets/health.proto'),
 },
};
```

- Client:

```
ClientsModule.register([
     {
       name: 'HERO_PACKAGE',
       transport: Transport.GRPC,
       options: {
         url: '0.0.0.0:50051',
         package: 'grpc.health.v1',
         protoPath: join(__dirname, 'assets/health.proto'),
         // credentials: credentials.createInsecure()
       },
     },
   ])
```

Then, I decide to check the logs inside the `linkerd` pod that is running for the client.
`kubectl logs pod/xxx-api-main-app-deployment-5fb5d4bf9f-ttwn5 -c linkerd-init`
and the output was this:

````
2020/07/25 16:37:50 Tracing this script execution as [1595695070]
2020/07/25 16:37:50 State of iptables rules before run:
2020/07/25 16:37:50 > iptables -t nat -vnL
2020/07/25 16:37:50 < Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
2020/07/25 16:37:50 > iptables -t nat -F PROXY_INIT_REDIRECT
2020/07/25 16:37:50 < iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
2020/07/25 16:37:50 > iptables -t nat -X PROXY_INIT_REDIRECT
2020/07/25 16:37:50 < iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
2020/07/25 16:37:50 Will ignore port(s) [4190 4191] on chain PROXY_INIT_REDIRECT
2020/07/25 16:37:50 Will redirect all INPUT ports to proxy
2020/07/25 16:37:50 > iptables -t nat -F PROXY_INIT_OUTPUT
2020/07/25 16:37:50 < iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
2020/07/25 16:37:50 > iptables -t nat -X PROXY_INIT_OUTPUT
2020/07/25 16:37:50 < iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
2020/07/25 16:37:50 Ignoring uid 2102
2020/07/25 16:37:50 Redirecting all OUTPUT to 4140
2020/07/25 16:37:50 Executing commands:
2020/07/25 16:37:50 > iptables -t nat -N PROXY_INIT_REDIRECT -m comment --comment proxy-init/redirect-common-chain/1595695070
2020/07/25 16:37:50 <
2020/07/25 16:37:50 > iptables -t nat -A PROXY_INIT_REDIRECT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 4190,4191 -j RETURN -m comment --comment proxy-init/ignore-port-4190,4191/1595695070
2020/07/25 16:37:50 <
2020/07/25 16:37:50 > iptables -t nat -A PROXY_INIT_REDIRECT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 4143 -m comment --comment proxy-init/redirect-all-incoming-to-proxy-port/1595695070
2020/07/25 16:37:50 <
2020/07/25 16:37:50 > iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j PROXY_INIT_REDIRECT -m comment --comment proxy-init/install-proxy-init-prerouting/1595695070
2020/07/25 16:37:50 <
2020/07/25 16:37:50 > iptables -t nat -N PROXY_INIT_OUTPUT -m comment --comment proxy-init/redirect-common-chain/1595695070
2020/07/25 16:37:50 <
2020/07/25 16:37:50 > iptables -t nat -A PROXY_INIT_OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 2102 -o lo ! -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j PROXY_INIT_REDIRECT -m comment --comment proxy-init/redirect-non-loopback-local-traffic/1595695070
2020/07/25 16:37:51 <
2020/07/25 16:37:51 > iptables -t nat -A PROXY_INIT_OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 2102 -j RETURN -m comment --comment proxy-init/ignore-proxy-user-id/1595695070
2020/07/25 16:37:51 <
2020/07/25 16:37:51 > iptables -t nat -A PROXY_INIT_OUTPUT -o lo -j RETURN -m comment --comment proxy-init/ignore-loopback/1595695070
2020/07/25 16:37:51 <
2020/07/25 16:37:51 > iptables -t nat -A PROXY_INIT_OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 4140 -m comment --comment proxy-init/redirect-all-outgoing-to-proxy-port/1595695070
2020/07/25 16:37:51 <
2020/07/25 16:37:51 > iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -j PROXY_INIT_OUTPUT -m comment --comment proxy-init/install-proxy-init-output/1595695070
2020/07/25 16:37:51 <
2020/07/25 16:37:51 > iptables -t nat -vnL
2020/07/25 16:37:51 < Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 PROXY_INIT_REDIRECT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* proxy-init/install-proxy-init-prerouting/1595695070 */
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 PROXY_INIT_OUTPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* proxy-init/install-proxy-init-output/1595695070 */
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
Chain PROXY_INIT_OUTPUT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 PROXY_INIT_REDIRECT  all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.1            owner UID match 2102 /* proxy-init/redirect-non-loopback-local-traffic/1595695070 */
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 2102 /* proxy-init/ignore-proxy-user-id/1595695070 */
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* proxy-init/ignore-loopback/1595695070 */
    0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* proxy-init/redirect-all-outgoing-to-proxy-port/1595695070 */ redir ports 4140
Chain PROXY_INIT_REDIRECT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 4190,4191 /* proxy-init/ignore-port-4190,4191/1595695070 */
    0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* proxy-init/redirect-all-incoming-to-proxy-port/1595695070 */ redir ports 4143
    ```
I'm not sure where the problem is, and thanks in advance for your help.
Hopefully this give you more context and you can point me out in the right direction.
````

Comment: Have you tried to use port-forward in the service to verify if your app return something? Because i didn't see the `containerPort` for the container `microservice-container`

Answer (score 0):

The iptables output from the Linkerd `proxy-init` looks fine.

Did you check the logs of the `linkerd-proxy` inside the container? That might help to understand what is happening.

It's also worth trying the `port-forward` test that @KoopaKiller recommends